# System GMM with R: issues with the multi-part formula for IVs and the sargan test results

Tags: r, plm, generalized-method-of-moments

I'm working on a panel dataset with ***N = 30*** countries and ***T = 15*** years. I'm using `R` and the `plm` package for my analysis.
Based on research by *Blundell-Bond (1998)* and *Arellano-Bover (1995)*, I decided to use the System-GMM onestep model, with only individual effects.
However, I'm a little confused about how to use the `pgmm` function, which requires a multi-part formula to specify the model with IVs and with the Sargan-Hansen test result I get.
To be more clear, here are some code examples I tried, the results of estimates and the `sargan` test. In my model I consider the lagged dependent variable and an exogenous regressor. To avoid making my post too long, I just report the models code and the main results as tidy as I can:

```
sy_gmm1 <- pgmm(log(GWPcap) ~ lag(log(GWPcap)) + log(GDPcap)|lag(log(GWPcap),2:15) + log(GDPcap), data = europanel, 
                index = c("country","year"), model = "onestep", effect = "individual", transformation = "ld")
        
sy_gmm2 <- pgmm(log(GWPcap) ~ lag(log(GWPcap)) + log(GDPcap)|lag(log(GWPcap),2:15) | log(GDPcap), data = europanel, 
                index = c("country","year"), model = "onestep", effect = "individual", transformation = "ld")
        
sy_gmm3 <- pgmm(log(GWPcap) ~ lag(log(GWPcap)) + log(GDPcap) | lag(log(GWPcap),2) + log(GDPcap), data = europanel, 
                index = c("country","year"), model = "onestep", effect = "individual", transformation = "ld")
        
sy_gmm4 <- pgmm(log(GWPcap) ~ lag(log(GWPcap)) + log(GDPcap)|lag(log(GWPcap),2) | log(GDPcap), data = europanel, 
                index = c("country","year"), model = "onestep", effect = "individual", transformation = "ld")
        
sy_gmm5 <- pgmm(log(GWPcap) ~ lag(log(GWPcap)) + log(GDPcap) | lag(log(GWPcap),2) + lag(log(GDPcap),1:2), data = europanel, 
                index = c("country","year"), model = "onestep", effect = "individual", transformation = "ld")
        
sy_gmm6 <- pgmm(log(GWPcap) ~ lag(log(GWPcap)) + log(GDPcap)|lag(log(GWPcap),2) | lag(log(GDPcap),1:2), data = europanel, 
                index = c("country","year"), model = "onestep", effect = "individual", transformation = "ld")

# Coefficients and p-values of estimates
  
                   Estimate       p.value Model
lag(log(GWPcap)) 0.90340911  1.525370e-86     1
log(GDPcap)      0.06214275  1.965823e-02     1
lag(log(GWPcap)) 0.97250426  0.000000e+00     2
log(GDPcap)      0.02222075  1.383774e-01     2
lag(log(GWPcap)) 0.81905400  2.615214e-47     3
log(GDPcap)      0.10822697  8.291284e-04     3
lag(log(GWPcap)) 0.82343976  4.873484e-16     4
log(GDPcap)      0.11164469  7.294118e-02     4
lag(log(GWPcap)) 0.84762245  2.754039e-87     5
log(GDPcap)      0.09281759  1.636567e-04     5
lag(log(GWPcap)) 0.86280993 3.843798e-104     6
log(GDPcap)      0.08809634  3.325890e-04     6

# Sargan test
                stat  df   p.value
    sargan1 30.00000 128 1.0000000
    sargan2 30.00000 104 1.0000000
    sargan3 30.00000  50 0.9888352
    sargan4 29.64127  26 0.2827384
    sargan5 30.00000  63 0.9998660
    sargan6 30.00000  28 0.3632178
```

As you can see in models 2, 4 and 6 I put the exogenous regressor `log(GDPcap)` in the third part of the formula, separating it from the lagged dependent instruments . I don't know if this is the right way to set the formula, as in the R documentation it is specified that it is needed for "normal instruments". What does it mean?
Given this doubt I wanted to do an experiment in model 6, using `lag(log(GDPcap))` and the results I got in the estimates, `log(GDPcap)` is significant, and in the Sargan test they seem to be apparently good.

Furthermore, I noticed the different results I got with the Sargan test, in particular regarding the degrees of freedom, which are very related to the number of instruments I'm using, and the p-value.
From what I have read around, using too many instruments can be a double-edged sword, especially given the size of my sample, and the Sargan-Hansen test could suffer, giving a too high p-value. So my question is which of these six models was written right and how should I interpret the results I got, both in the estimates (in some models the exogenous regressor is not significant) and in the test?

I hope I was clear and that someone can resolve my doubts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cross post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491992/system-gmm-with-r-issues-with-multi-part-formula-for-ivs-and-the-sargan-test-re

Comment: Sorry for the double post. I realized that maybe it's better to ask on Cross Validate, because it's more of a statistical question than about the code. For the code I just needed to figure out how to set up the formula. If necessary I delete the post here and leave only the one on CV. Thanks.